# php get redirected url

Tags: php, curl, redirect

```
function get_redirect_final_target($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); // follow redirects
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1); // set referer on redirect
    curl_exec($ch);
    $target = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
    curl_close($ch);
    if ($target)
        return $target;
    return false;
}
```

my original link

```
$url = "http://www.mylink";
```

echo redirected link, but it will echo the same link since it cannot detect any redirection header. but my link will have a 302 redirect.

```
echo get_redirect_final_target($url);
```

using other normal redirect link will work, but my link should redirect, but it cannot get the header location link.
Any help is greatly appreaciated!

Comment: is the `get_redirect_target` correct shouldn't it be `get_redirect_final_target` ?

Comment: use `curl_error()` and you will get a SSL error

Comment: I just miss a word, but it has the same problem. you can check my original url, it will redirect to a video. but the script cannot detect the redirection.

Comment: is it the SSL problem caused the issue? how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use get_headers PHP function and see if you get 200 or 302.

Comment: in firefox addon http live header to test the url, the original url will have
`HTTP/2.0 302 Found`
and the redirected url will have 
`HTTP/2.0 200 OK`

Comment: that's normal.. you get 302 for each redirect, then on final real page you get 200.